# Custom Script for Installing Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: batch-file, scripting, adobe, acrobat

I do not think this question has been clearly asked before here on this site. I have scoured Google in hopes of finding a solution, but the information is scattered around the web and difficult to piece together in a timely fashion (with my limited scripting knowledge anyway). So, any help would be appreciated, and if there are any questions about what I'm trying to accomplish here, feel free to ask. I am reaching out because when it comes to creating scripts that are more complicated than merely launching an executable, my knowledge is very limited.

**What I am trying to do:**

Ultimately, I will be using ManageEngine Desktop Central to push a configuration out to remote computers on our domain/network. The more simple goal, that I just can't seem to find success with, is getting a batch file that can be as easy as running it and successfully installing Adobe Acrobat DC (Not the free Adobe Reader application). I would like to have a batch file that checks to see if the install folder is there, and if it is, uninstall it to eliminate the message that is prompted stating "Error 1316. The specified account already exists." or any other traces of Acrobat that would cause this install error. Once the safeguards are in place to avoid install errors, such as the error previously mentioned, it gets more simple. After that, I just want Adobe Acrobat to install, then I want to remove the shortcut "Adobe Creative Cloud.lnk" from all the users' desktops so they only see the "Adobe Acrobat DC" shortcut.

UPDATE**

Okay, in the time I posted the original post, I have tried throwing together a batch file, but it still will not work. I am using a 3rd party service to deploy this config, so contacting Adobe would not be helpful. I don't expect most people to be familiar with ManageEngine Desktop Central, but that is why I need a batch file, which Adobe support cannot help me with. what I have right now is:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC" (
rmdir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC" 
goto :install
) ELSE (
ECHO Acrobat Folder Doesn't Exist goto :install
)


:install

S:\Adobe_CC\AcrobatPro\AcrobatDC\AdobeAcrobatDC\Build\setup.exe --silent



IF /I "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" (
ECHO execution failed
)
```

Comment: This is not an "I have an issue with my supplied batch file", type question but a "how do I deploy a specific piece of software with conditional options" question. As such it is out of the scope, _(read as off-topic)_, and too broad for Stack Overflow. Might I suggest requesting support from the software manuafacturer or a forum/community dedicated to that specific piece of software.

Comment: I understand how you can think that, but I don't need to know flags or anything of how to install that software. I really need to have a batch file that does a check and depending on what it finds, call an action to install, or not to install the software I have as well as deleting the desktop shortcut. I don't have a batch file, just an MSI and EXE, that's why I'm looking for assistance here. My main goal isn't even to know or find out why the error is happening, I just want the batch file to delete the install directory, if it's present.

Comment: I was trying to be polite and save you from having to watch this thread for answers which are unlikely to come. Your question is off-topic and too broad for this site which is for members to help others with issues they encounter from running their own created code. Without researching yourself and providing your own problematic `batch file` there is nothing for us to answer.

Comment: @Compo Okay, I apologize, this is the first time I've ever actually posted for help in a long while, if at all, for a specific issue. I have updated the OP. I was trying to throw together a batch file even before I posted the original post. So I included what I have so far, which is more than what I had to start.

Comment: Do you really think that simply removing a programs installation directory in Windows is the same as uninstalling it? Are you aware that the specific piece of software you are checking for can be located at places other than `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC"`? Have you ever heard of the [Acrobat Customization Wizard DC for Windows](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Wizard/WizardDC/index.html)? If you take a look you will see that you can create installation packages capable of checking for/removing older versions and the creation or otherwise of shortcuts and more etc.

Comment: @Compo Yes, I know it's not the same as uninstalling it, but for the sake of removing those folders manually, which I've done, to get it to install then that's why I was going to do it that way. I know that there is a folder in AppData>LocalAdobe>Acrobat and another in ProgramData, but I didn't see any folder for Acrobat. I know of the folders, I just need help with the language/code to get one folder to be removed and I can do the rest. I have not heard of that, even with my hours of searching throughout the day, so I would've never heard of it anyway. I will check it out.

Comment: @Devan, uninstall routines, perform so much more than removing files, especially with software like Acrobat DC. If an existing version is installed and you don't wish to install side by side, _(not my recommendation)_, then it should be uninstalled properly before installing to the same system. Ignoring that advice could be catastrophic for your workstations moving forward.

Comment: @Compo I understand. With that said, I have taken your advice and looked for other alternatives and found that creating a new package using the downloadable Creative Cloud Packager, instead of using the online packager, succeeded when using `S:\Adobe_CC\AcrobatPro\Adobe Acrobat DC Pro\Build\setup.exe --silent` for the configuration in Desktop Central. I also got it working where it does not place the Adobe Creative Cloud Application Manager icon on the desktop. I do not know what was wrong with the 5+ other new packages I made before that, but it's working now. Thank you for all your advice!

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is a bit different, due to the fact most of the work is done in ManageEngine Desktop Central. What fixed the issue, in my case, was downloading the Creative Cloud Packager (CCPLauncher.exe) and advancing through the wizard. I disabled the end user being able to install updates or install other products. The only switches left on were the ones to allow my IT department to remotely manage and push out updates. I then ran through with defaults and selected only Adobe Acrobat DC [Pro] (the Adobe Creative Cloud Application Manager will be grayed out and cannot be unselected).

After the package was created and placed in my network share that contains all of my software executables, I opened and logged into Desktop Central. The first step was to create the **Package** in DTC. You do this by clicking **Software Deployment** tab, then click **"+ Add Package"** and select your operating system. Once you've done that, click **"Create Package manually."** After that, select the radio that fits the file type you are working with, in my case, I selected "MSIEXEC/EXE/ISS/Command." Then name your package and select the current license type (I selected Commerical). After that, in the field labeled "MSI File Name with Network path*:", enter the path of the executable/MSI file including the file and extension. Under **Installation** Enter the same path, if the same path applies here, which in most cases it will, but leave the file name and extension off. This is just for the folder where the installer resides. Then click the **Add Package** button below. At the top, I then clicked **Configurations** then on the left pane, **Configuration.** I chose to **"Install/Uninstall Software"** and selected **Computer.** I ran through the usual and named the configuration, then selected the "EXE" radio button and find the "Package" you just made and be sure the drop down list below that is set to Install Completely (or another option depending what your file is). For "Apply Deployment Policy:" select the correct one; I selected DC Default Policy. Below that, select the User/Computers you want to apply this configuration to on your network and click "Deploy" or "Deploy Immediately" and you are done. I made a Security Group in Active Directory and added machines to that and then in DTC, chose to deploy it to the **Group** that I named "Adobe Acrobat DC Pro" in AD. My configuration deployed successfully and I was able to recreate that successful deployment on every new computer I added to the group in AD. Hopefully there is someone out there that ran into the same problem with Desktop Central that now has somewhat of an answer. If this method does not work for you, hopefully you can find success with your issue.